# Discrete Fourier Transform C++

Tags: c++, fft, complextype

I'm trying to write simple DFT and IDFT functions which will be my core for future projects. Trouble means that IDFT returns different value from input value, and i can't understand, where is the mistake.
Below my source code:

```
vector<double> input;
vector<double> result;
vector<complex<double>> output;

double IDFT(int n)
{
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    int N = output.size();
    for(int k = 0; k < N; k++)
    {
        double value = abs(output[k]);
        a+= cos((2 * M_PI * k * n) / N) * value;
        b+= sin((2 * M_PI * k * n) / N) * value;
    }
    complex<double> temp(a, b);
    double result = abs(temp);
    result /= N;
    return result;
}
complex<double> DFT(double in, int k)
{
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    int N = input.size();
    for(int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        a+= cos((2 * M_PI * k * n) / N) * input[n];
        b+= -sin((2 * M_PI * k * n) / N) * input[n];
    }
    complex<double> temp(a, b);
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    input.push_back(55);
    input.push_back(15);
    input.push_back(86);
    input.push_back(24);
    input.push_back(66);
    input.push_back(245);
    input.push_back(76);

    for(int k = 0; k < input.size(); k++)
    {
        output.push_back(DFT(input[k], k));
        cout << "#" << k << ":\t" << input[k] << " \t>> abs: " << abs(output[k]) << " >> phase: " << arg(output[k]) << endl;
    }
    for(int n = 0; n < output.size(); n++)
    {
        result.push_back(IDFT(n));
        cout << result[n] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is not just an educational exercise, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: http://www.fftw.org/

Comment: Maybe, if i decide to compile it for some microcontroller, i won't have problems with any additional libraries, and also, i must understand how it works in low level.

Comment: Read about floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Strongly recommend https://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/ - small, self contained, fast.

Comment: @ZDF This doesn't seem to be a floating point issue- I would expect close, but not exact results if that were the case.

Comment: Thanks, but i want understand where is my mistake, i don't need other libraries.

Comment: @RomanKulaha have you used a debugger on this yet? print statements inside the functions?  It should be pretty easy to figure out what went wrong if you understand the algorithm...

Comment: Input: 55
15                                                          86                                                          24                                                          66                                                          245                                                         76                        Output:                                254.121                                                     64.0808                                                     42.3543
50.0043
50.0043
42.3543
64.080

Comment: For future projects it's definitely better using existing stuff. There are plenty of such a projects on the web made for embedded sytems. E.g. this one https://github.com/kosme/arduinoFFT. I used it and it works fine. If you have educational purpose you should consider to post the answer to the math community https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BenJones I am not near a computer. Now that I see the output, it looks like you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inverse Fourier transform is obviously broken: you ignore the arguments of the complex numbers `output[k]`.

It should look like this:

```
double IDFT(size_t n)
{
    const auto ci = std::complex<double>(0, 1);
    std::complex<double> result;
    size_t N = output.size();
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N; k++)
        result += std::exp((1. / N) * 2 * M_PI * k * n * ci) * output[k];
    result /= N;
    return std::abs(result);
}
```

**Edit.**

If you want to separate real and imaginary parts explicitly, you can use:

```
double IDFT(size_t n)
{
    double a = 0;
    size_t N = output.size();
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N; k++)
    {
        auto phase = (2 * M_PI * k * n) / N;
        a += cos(phase) * output[k].real() - sin(phase) * output[k].imag();
    }
    a /= N;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: In case the `exp` is confusing, this is equivalent to changing `value` to `output[k].real()` and `output[k].imag()` in OP's `IDFT()` accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

**For Intel cores computers:**

There is a library of Intel- `IPP`. It offers many functions with a very high performance. It is very hard to write something that is faster than their functions, due to the vectors operations they use. Try it: https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-use-intel-ipp-s-1d-fourier-transform-functions